# How to sign multiple pages of a PDF using Chilkat based on a page number list?

Tags: digital-signature, chilkat

I'm working with the Chilkat library in my project, and I need to sign specific pages of a PDF based on a list of page numbers. Can someone provide a code example or guidance on how to achieve this?

Put signature based on page number list

Comment: `sign specific pages of a PDF based on a list of page numbers` do you mean sign if there is one page and not sign if the document has more pages? (or something like this)

Comment: @MichałLipok                     
I need to sign specific pages of a PDF based on a list of page numbers. This means I have a list of page numbers, and I need to add a signature to each of these pages, not just a single page.                 
For example, if I have a list of page numbers [2, 4, 6], I want to apply a signature to those specific pages, not just the first page.

Comment: Aha... so you do not mean Sign specific page (sgned is entire PDF document).  What you wanted here is to add stamp/visualization for specific pages.

Comment: @MichałLipok.                                  Yes, I want to sign the PDF and display my signature on all the listed page numbers.

Comment: How did you determine the correct pages ? I mean which technology ? and when you determine this page - before you sign them ?

Answer (score 2):

A cryptographic signature would sign the entire PDF document.  Signing individual pages doesn't really make sense.

When a PDF is signed, a byte range of the PDF is digested, and the digest is signed.  Typically, the byte range is in 2 parts -- the the span before the space allocated for the signature, and the span following the signature to the end of the PDF document.

The PDF format is such that it is composed of objects, and those objects are interspersed throughout the document. They can be versioned. The objects can be encapsulated into compressed stream objects.  Therefore, the things that make up a page can be scattered around in a PDF.  I can't even imagine what it means to "sign a page".  What byte ranges within the PDF represent the page?  It's impossible to really define.  Also PDF objects contained in one page can be contained in others.

Anyway, it makes no sense to "sign a page".

Perhaps you are wanting a visual indication on each page that the overall PDF is signed.  But that is something different..

Comment: `Perhaps you are wanting a visual indication on each page that the overall PDF is signed. But that is something different..`

@gyani already said exactly that here:
`Yes, I want to sign the PDF and display my signature on all the listed page numbers.`

It is also interestning for me.
So I would like to ask: Is it possible ?